# Show that if $\int_I f=0$ for all interval then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ integrable on $\mathbb R$ and continuous. I have to show that if for all interval $I\subset \mathbb R$, $$\int_If=0$$
then $f=0$.

**My attempts**

Suppose $f\neq 0$. Then, there is a $c\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f(c)\neq 0$. Suppose WLOG that $f(c)>0$. By continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $f|_{[c-\delta,c+\delta]}>0$ and thus $$\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f>0$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $f=0$. (Notice that I can use the result $f>0\implies \int f>0$.)

Do you think it's correct ? It looks to easy, that's why I ask you.

Comment: Yes, It is correct.

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Since there is consensus that your approach is correct, would you mind adding your attempt as an answer to the question? (This would be in order to get the question out of the unanswered questions list).

Comment: Good solution, but I would bet that most people here would have suggested that you consider the function $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$ which apparently is everywhere zero (no matter what $a$ you happen to choose).

Comment: Yes its correct